# User Profile Creation exception in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-userprofile

We've a Sharepoint 2010 application where we create user profile in AD programmatically,
and then use that data from AD to further create a Sharepoint 2010 profile.
Sometimes we get the following error:

Appreciate your help.

ERROR:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done_   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.Win32.AdvApi.LookupAccountName(String lpSystemName, String lpAccountName, IntPtr Sid, Int32& cbSid, StringBuilder ReferencedDomainName, Int32& cchReferencedDomainName, SID_NAME_USE& peUse)_

CODE:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSiteUrl))
{
site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
UserProfile user = null;
HttpContext oldContext = HttpContext.Current;
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
HttpContext.Current = null;
UserProfileManager currentUserProfileManager = new UserProfileManager(context);
bool userexist = false;
try
{
user = currentUserProfileManager.GetUserProfile(accountName);
userexist = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
userexist = false;

}

 if (currentUserProfileManager != null)
{
if (!userexist)
{
try
{
user = currentUserProfileManager.CreateUserProfile(accountName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw;
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is impossible to create a user using sharepoint tools. You need to first create an account in AD using, for example, this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-Using

And only then set up replication of profiles in the sharepoint

Comment: Hi IaRaptor, actually that's exactly what we are doing. We first create an account in AD programmatically then use that account details of that AD account created to create a SharePoint profile. And while doing that sometimes we are getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Hello, Akash. I think you shouldn't create user profiles by hand or with custom code, when Sharepoint can do it for you. Use Profile Service and Forefront Manager to configure user synchronization.
Maybe this will help?
[link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/how-to-configure-synchronization-connection-for-user-profile-in-sharepoint-2010/#:~:text=Start%20Full%20Synchronization.-,Go%20to%20Central%20Administration%20%3D>%20Application%20management%20%3D>%20Manage%20service,Active%20Directory%20to%20SharePoint%202010.)